# Shrinkwrap vertex group of modified model to vertex group of shape-key'd Source model

Tags: shape-keys, snapping, shrinkwrap

I am working on modding a player character for a video game. I duplicated the character mesh, added geometry and modified it a good amount to make it les generic and more defined for muscle and body shape. What I want to do is somehow match up the neck, wrists, and general size changes to the source model shape-keys(morphs), so that I don't need to modify armor and other parts of the game.

What I've done so far is shrink wrap the whole model with a custom vert group that blends into the areas I've modified, then I've been vertex by vertex snapping to the source model and manually blending in the changes to match the wrists and neck to match up with parts that I am not modifying.

Is there any quicker way? This is taking hours to do what I feel should be simpler in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

Using the Mesh Data Transfer addon (found on GumRoad) I was able to transfer the meshes and only apply them to the vert group I made to blend the shape keys into my changes. After that worked, mostly, I was able to sculpt the differences and blend them nicely in the shape keys.

keys to this working were using the "closest" shearch meathod, choosing "Shape Keys" as attribute to transfer, and also selecting "snap shape key to closest vertex", and "exclude Muted": the magnet and checkmark on the selection button.

[image]